# Getting an Configuration Error with the Role Provider after publishing my ASP.NET MVC4 to host

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC4 web application. I'm using entity framework, and my database is in my host (i'm using HostGator). I changed the RoleProvider to be in this database as well (instead of the default MVC configuration).
My website works just fine in my computer (using VS2012), but when I tried to upload all the website to HostGator, i'm getting this exception:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service       this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file         appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Source Error: 


Line 62:       <providers>
Line 63:         <clear />
Line 64:         <add name="RFProviders" type="RFProject.Models.Bussiness.RFProviders, RFProject" connectionStringName="RFContext" applicationName="RFProject" writeExceptionsToEventLog="true" />
Line 65:       </providers>
Line 66:     </roleManager>

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

This is the exception i can see in the source of the page:

```
<!-- 
[VerificationException]: Operation could destabilize the runtime.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCollection`1.CollectionData..ctor()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCollection`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StructuralType..ctor()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ComplexType..ctor()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataItem..cctor()
[TypeInitializationException]: The type initializer for &#39;System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataItem&#39; threw an exception.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.PrimitiveType.GetEdmPrimitiveTypes()
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TypeExtensions..cctor()
[TypeInitializationException]: The type initializer for &#39;System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TypeExtensions&#39; threw an exception.
   at RFProject.Models.Bussiness.RFProviders..ctor()
[TargetInvocationException]: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreatePublicInstance(Type type)
   at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType)
[ConfigurationErrorsException]: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (D:\...\web.config line 64)
   at System.Web.Security.Roles.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule.OnEnter(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
--><!-- 
This error page might contain sensitive information because ASP.NET is configured to show verbose error messages using &lt;customErrors mode="Off"/&gt;. Consider using &lt;customErrors mode="On"/&gt; or &lt;customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/&gt; in production environments.-->
```

and this is my whole web.config file:

And this is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RFContext" connectionString="***" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <!--<trust level="Medium"/>-->
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <globalization culture="en-gb" uiCulture="auto:en-gb" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="RFContext" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordFormat="Hashed" applicationName="RFProject" name="AspNetSqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="RFProviders" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPROLES" cookieTimeout="30" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="All">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="RFProviders" type="RFProject.Models.Bussiness.RFProviders, RFProject" connectionStringName="RFContext" applicationName="RFProject" writeExceptionsToEventLog="true" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

</configuration>
```

Without commenting this line:

```
<trust level="Medium"/>
```

i'm getting this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using <location allowOverride="false"> from an inherited configuration file.

Source Error: 


Line 26:   
Line 27:   <system.web>
Line 28:     <trust level="Medium"/>
Line 29:     <customErrors mode="Off" />
Line 30:     <globalization culture="en-gb" uiCulture="auto:en-gb" />
```

Iv'e been trying so many things, but I just don't know what should I do...
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Was HostGator able to help you through your issue? I'm having the same error with them of needing to set a higher trust level and not being able to.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem seems to be related to Entity Framework rather than the web.config. As you can see in the stack trace the constructor for your provider is being called:

```
at RFProject.Models.Bussiness.RFProviders..ctor()
```

but then you have other errors (you have to look above that line, not below). Maybe some problem with the Entity Framework version used by HostGator?

The second problem is because some web.config settings can be (and are) defined at server level (IIS here I imagine) and sometime they can be set as "non-overridable". This seems to be the case with HostGator and the `<trust ...>` setting. Nothing you can do except have a chat with them...